# ikea bathroom sink leaking at connection. what is this connection called?

Tags: plumbing

hi my sink is leaking at the circled connection but only when the faucet is fully opened. why would it only leak then? does anyone know what this connection is called? would plumbers putty fix it? thank you

here is a link to a video of the leak:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1llQKRdvV4AkaXD0lKVuw43zPYVRwpyfq/view?usp=drivesdk

[image]

Comment: It looks like it is missing any kind of seal, use some silicone to seal it

Comment: Don't use silicone to seal plumbing. It should be glued, screwed or use the proper gaskets, depending on how it was supposed to be sealed in the first place. Silicone is a sign of desperation and hackery, not a proper repair.

Answer (score 2):

There is an o-ring the seats the connection between those two pieces of the low profile p-trap.  The o-ring is seated on the male portion of the p-trap assembly.  It is possible that o-ring is damaged or isn't seated correctly - I believe it sits in a grove or against the flange on the male piece.  Those two pieces are just pushed together over the o-ring so they will pull apart and you can inspect the o-ring.

There can be any number of reasons why it only leaks on high flow.  Perhaps the flow exceeds the outflow to the drain and the water backing up to that point puts pressure on it in the opposite direction.

Comment: And OP appears to have plenty of head room for a traditional drain, to eliminate that low-pro trap that seems to be finicky.  Well, not really trap, more like tailpiece—the trap is further below.

Comment: This is exactly correct; those pieces slide/extend/telescope using an o-ring seal. I would disassemble it and slather those components with waterproof plumber's grease.

Comment: OP probably has drawers in this unit - that is typically the only reason the ikea vanity will come with the low profile trap.